# Get Unity Blend Tree to update based on player rotation (mouse position)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, trigonometry, game-development

I'm working on the animations for a character in a top down game. I got the animations to work when the player is moving forwards towards the top, however, whenever I rotate the player with the mouse (to aim) the forward animation is now left/right, etc, etc. I'm using Unity3d and C# with blend tree animations.

[image: Blend Tree]
[image: Blend Tree 1]
[image: Variable]

The code I'm using is straightforward:

```
animator.SetFloat("VelX", playerInput.Horizontal);
animator.SetFloat("VelY", playerInput.Vertical);
```

I can't figure out how to make the forward animation play whenever I'm moving TOWARDS the mouse position.

My Solution:

```
var heading = Input.mousePosition - this.transform.position;
var distance = heading.magnitude;
var dir = heading / distance;
animator.SetFloat("VelX", playerInput.Horizontal * Mathf.Cos(dir));
animator.SetFloat("VelY", playerInput.Vertical * Mathf.Sin(dir));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may have figured this out already but I just had the same issue and I just found out a way to do this. Hopefully it helps others.

```
 Vector3 inputVector = (Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) + (Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));

 Vector3 animationVector = _playerModel.transform.InverseTransformDirection(inputVector);

 var VelocityX = animationVector.x;
 var VelocityZ = animationVector.z;
 
 this._playerAnimator.SetFloat("x", VelocityX);
 this._playerAnimator.SetFloat("z", VelocityZ);
```

I my case I have my movement script on a parent empty object. This object rotates the child player model, which is the one getting animated. If you do this then you will need to reference the player model like I am doing. Otherwise you can you transform if you are using the parent object.

I am using a character controller on my parent object not a rigidbody, but it may work the same either way.

From my understanding the key part is 'InverseTransformDirection' which is taking my physical world horizontal and vertical vectors and then converting them based on the rotation of my player model. This then makes the movements be relative to the players rotation rather than the worlds rotation and I can move backwards or strafe correctly as I am moving my mouse for rotation and wasd for movement.